# Dotnet-Dump on linux x64: How to export heap?

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Im using `dotnet dump collect -p 1` on my Asp.Net 7.0.9 api running on AKS using the default image from microsoft and when opening the file on `Windbg` and trying to `!heap -?` I get an error "No export heap found"... how can I capture the heap on the dump?

Comment: Same problem here. According to the documentation of the dotnet-dump tool, the type defaults to 'Full' which should include the heap. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @RobertHegner no, sorry... I ended up opening a ticket at microsoft we used a bunch of other tools